# Theos iOS 7 Apps/Tweaks

Tags: ios7, theos, cydia-substrate

I want to make tweaks and apps for iOS 7. I install theos on my iPod Touch 5 (running iOS7) and I created a simple app. The thing is, the app only supports the 3.5 inch screen and it is styled like iOS 6. Is there a way I can make iPhone 5 optimised apps and iOS 7 styled apps without using a computer?? Do I need to install an updated theos?? I installed BigBossRecommended Tools and perl and git and then ran the command installtheos3 in mobile terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have the iOS 7 SDK, I am suspect that the iOS 6 SDK is bundled with BigBossRecomended Tools. See the [iphonedevwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#For_iOS) for where to put the iOS 7 SDK. See [retrieving SDKs](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Retrieving_SDKs) for how to get a hold of the proper SDK.